# Using foreign key and SQL Statements

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

Two MySQL tables

Table 1 includes: account_id [Primary Key, Auto Increment]

Table 2 includes: customer_id [Primary Key, Auto Increment], account_id [Foreign Key]

The problem now is when I'm executing an INSERT INTO statement that involves the two tables (The two tables is empty at this moment), it would enter the values in the first table then it would release an error in the second table.

I assumed that the problem is that the second table did not receive the first table account_id so it would throw an error at my program.

```
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("START TRANSACTION;INSERT INTO account_table(uname,pass,level) VALUES (?,?,?);INSERT INTO customer_table(fname,lname,mname) VALUES(?,?,?);COMMIT;", con)
```

Is there somehow any way that the customer_table would automatically update its foreign key when the account table successfully records the value? I tried CASCADE but it's not updating on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Your table definitions should look like this:

```
Accounts
--------
ID (identity column)
uname
passHash
level

Customers
---------
ID (identity column)
AcccountID (foreign key)
fname
lname
mname
```

Note that I changed the `pass` to `passHash`. **NEVER** store passwords in plain text.

Now you can update your sql like this:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @AccountID int;
INSERT INTO account_table(uname,pass,level) VALUES (?,?,?);
Set @AccountID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO customer_table(AccountID, fname,lname,mname) VALUES(@AccountID, ?,?,?);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: It does not store any data :/